# HC-SR501 Not working as expected

Tags: gpio, sensor

No matter what I do, I get tons of 'false positives'.  Occasionally the thing settles down, but it seems the majority of time it's:

1. registering some kind of movement for about 3 seconds
2. waiting without movement for about 4-8 seconds.  Repeat #1

I checked the wiring over and over and tried two different units.  Basing off guidelines presented [here](https://www.mbtechworks.com/projects/pir-motion-sensor-with-raspberry-pi.html)

Multimeter seems to corroborate this (seeing 3.3V come and go) - I expect that though when sitting right next to the PIR.

EDIT:

Photos coming.

Has anyone encountered this behavior?  Is it the kind of behavior one would expect?  What are some recommended steps to diagnosing this issue?

I have a fair bit of computer equipment separated by a wall with an open door (not line of sight) right about 7-8m from the PIR sensor.  Is it possible for the heat of those to affect it?

Comment: What is your question?  If you have a specific question then please also provide more information, e.g. a photo of your connections and a listing of the software you are using.   Please EDIT your question to include any extra information, do not add it in comments.

Comment: This PIR sensor might be faulty. Do you have another one to try?

Comment: Mark I only have the two units I've tried.  At the moment (and presumably over past 6 hours) it's "settled" more and at the moment is behaving as expected